# Sharepoint 2007: how to do anonym users count, does it happen something if I change sessionstate to inproc?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to count the anonym users online in a Sharepoint 2007 website (in a farm).

The classic way of doing this in .NET is:

```
   protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Application.Lock();
            Application["online"] = Convert.ToInt16(Application["online"]) + 1;
            Application.UnLock();

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

        Application.Lock();
        Application["online"] = Convert.ToInt16(Application["online"]) - 1;
        Application.UnLock();

    }
```

You can't do this, if you are using a Sql server sessionstate, because Session_End does never fire, it fires only Session_Start.

As you know, the web.config in Sharepoint Websites is configure with SQL server for sessions.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="1" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" partitionResolverType="Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SqlSessionStateResolver, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

This is because you can share sessions between different servers as they are implemented in the SQL SERVER database. 
I don't care about this, because we are using a load balancer, so users keep the sessions thanks to this.

So my first solution is to change the SessionState to "Inproc". The user session will be kept in the same server thanks to the load balancer.

But, second, I don't know if Application["online"] which is the property that will save the users online, will be shared between the different servers, or every server will have a different value if I use Inproc. This could be the real problem of changing to Sql Server sessionstate.

In summary:

1.- I need to know if Application is shared between servers even if inProc is in use in a Sharpoint farm.

2.-Consequences/ problems / errors generated from changing to Inproc.

3.-Do you find any other solution to implement an anonym users' count if you have a sql server sessionstate and using Sharepoint 2007?
I have found this solution using cache:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SessionEndStatePersister.aspx

The simplest, the best.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Application state is local to the server, regardless of how session state is handled.
2. If you use Inproc, you have to make sure that the load balancer keeps track of users, and *always* sends a sepcific user to the same server, or the session will be lost.
3. You can keep a local count of users per server, and periodically update a record in a table in the database with the count from each server. You can then get the total number of users by summing up the count from all the rows in the table.

Comment: Don't you think that Application is shared in a Sharepoint farm? My doubt is if it would be shared if I use inproc. do you have any reference?

Comment: We are thinking about doing sql access for every page request and insert in a customized datatable where we register session.ids and time of access. We insert or update and delete in every access. Haven't found any better solution

Comment: @netadictos: No, the Application context is not shared across servers. Note "on a single Web server" in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx

Comment: @netadictos: You can keep track of the sessions locally on each server and only update the count in the database periodically if you want to reduce the number of database accesses.